# How to call method of a component from a controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a component that represent a map and after an action in my controller I want to call a method on the component to center the map. The code looks like this

```
App.PlacesController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions : {
    centerMap : function () {
        // how to call from here to GoogleMapComponent.centerMap ??
    }
  }
});


App.GoogleMapComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  centerMap : function () {
  }
});
```

template

```
{{google-map}}
<button {{action "centerMap"}}>Center Map</button>
```

I have found a workaround but I don't think this is the Ember way of doing this.

```
{{google-map viewName="mapView"}}
<button class="center-map">Center Map</button>

App.PlacesView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement : function () {
    this.$(".center-map").click(this.clickCenterMap.bind(this));
  },

  clickCenterMap : function () {
    this.get("mapView").centerMap();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 23):

In Ember, views (Components are glorified views) know about their controller, but controllers do NOT know about views. This is by design (MVC) to keep things decoupled, and so you can have many views that are being "powered" by a single controller, and the controller is none the wiser. So when thinking about the relationship, changes can happen to a controller and a view will react to those changes. So, just to reiterate, you should never try to access a view/component from within a controller.

There are a few options I can think of when dealing with your example.

1. Make the button part of your component! Components are meant to handle user input, like button clicks, so you may want to consider making the button a part of the map component and handle clicks in the actions hash of your component. If this buttons is always going to accompany the map component, then I certainly recommend this approach.
2. You could have a boolean property on your controller like `isCentered`, and when the button is clicked it's set to true. In your component you can bind to that controller's property, and react whenever that property changes. It's a two-way binding so you can also change your locally bound property to false if the user moves the map, for example.

   Controller:

   ```
   ...
   isCentered: false,
   actions: {
       centerMap: {
           this.set('isCentered', true);
       }
   }
   ...
   ```

   Component:

   ```
   ...
   isCenteredBinding: 'controller.isCentered',
   onIsCenteredChange: function () {
       //do your thing
   }.observes('isCentered'),
   ...
   ```
3. Jeremy Green's solution can work if you mix in the Ember.Evented mixin into the controller (which adds the pub/sub `trigger` and `on` methods)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, maybe I'm confused with the Ember MVC pattern. I am new in Ember.
I thought that Controller communicate to views via calling methods and views should communicate to Controllers via events, but it seems to be just the opposite.

In this slides https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1y5AZN0qbjkMuyxxicfV_XPe_aLePdnkuR69tUOQTVo0/edit#slide=id.g121e8eb25_238 (slide 7) there is some direct communication between views and controllers but the mechanism is not specified.

Who is responsible for creating views and call render or destroy method? Is not the controller?

Comment: the ember1.6,component's controller not the mvc's controller.

Comment: 1) here makes the most sense, if the button has to live somewhere else in the dom its always worth considering the ember-wormhole addon

Answer (score 9):

You can use `on` to have your component listen for an event from the controller, then you can use `trigger` in the controller to emit an event.

So in your component you might have something like this:

```
didInsertElement : function(){
  this.get('controller').on('recenter', $.proxy(this.recenter, this));
},

recenter : function(){
  this.get("mapView").centerMap()
}
```

And in your controller you could have :

```
actions : {
  centerMap : function () {
    this.trigger('recenter');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Ember 1.1.2 and the EmberController doesn't have a trigger method.
This is the correct pattern? The controller should launch events and the view listen to them?

Comment: @axelhzf To trigger events and listen on them you need to create an object by adding the `Ember.Evented` mixin, like so: `App.someController = Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.Evented, { ... });` , then you can subscribe to events and raise events using the methods from the `Ember.Evented` mixin.

Comment: I like this solution, but I haven't seen the use of $.proxy before - can you clarify exactly what that does?

Comment: @KevinJhangiani $.proxy makes sure that `this` is bound to the correct thing when the `recenter` function is called. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: I think to add event on parent controller from the component you need to write `this.get('targetObject')` instead of `this.get('controller')`

Answer (score 6):

Bind a component property to the controller property in the template:

```
    {{google-map componentProperty=controllerProperty}}
```

Then observe the component property in the component:

```
    onChange: function () {
        // Do your thing
    }.observes('componentProperty')
```

Now every time `controllerProperty` is changed in the controller, `onChange` in the component will be called.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26105073/1438809), second paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's OK to have a reference in your controller to your component. It's true that your component encapsulates it's own behaviour, but public methods like `reload` etc. are perfectly fine.

My solution for this is to pass the current `controller` to the component and set a property on the controller within the component.

**Example**

template.hbs:

`{{#component delegate=controller property="refComponent"}}`

component.js:

```
init: function() {
   this._super.apply(this, arguments);

   if (this.get("delegate")) {
      this.get('delegate').set(this.get("property") || "default", this);
   }
}
```

Now in your controller you can simply get a reference to your component with `this.get("refComponent")`.

Steffen

Comment: While I find this being against the Ember philoshopy, I found myself in need of doing this. I will probably have to rewrite my code later on but it works as a great workaround. Thanks Steffen.

Comment: including controller will trigger assertion error for ember version >2

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your component call:

```
var parentController = this.get('targetObject');
```

See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_targetObject