# Can an Ember component observe a controller property?

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller and a component. when the component is rendered, it is passed on in this manner:

```
{{modal-filter feature=feature parentController=this.controller}}
```

where feature is a param passed in via controller to handlebars, and parentController is the controller.

Now, in the controller itself, there is an property (an array). let's call that array requiredValues.

Now within a controller/component itself, we can easily set:

```
valueObserver : function(){
     ...
}.observes('requiredValues')
```

However, I need to observe this controller property from a the modal-filter component. So in the modal-filter component, what would I put as the observer function:

```
valueObserver : function(){
     ...
}.observes(???)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### What you shouldn't do, but I'll tell you how for completeness

If you're passing the controller in, you can just watch an item on the `parentController` property, **though I wouldn't recommend this at all**.

```
valueObserver : function(){
     ...
}.observes('parentController.requiredValues')
```

This would assume the entire array is being replaced, not just an item added, or changed.

#### Item Added or Removed

```
valueObserver : function(){
     ...
}.observes('parentController.requiredValues.[]')
```

#### Item Property foo changed on one of the requiredValues items

```
valueObserver : function(){
     ...
}.observes('parentController.requiredValues.@each.foo')
```

### What you should do

Instead of passing in the controller, just pass in the property, and observe the property.

```
{{modal-filter feature=feature property=someProperty}}


propertyObserver : Ember.observer('property', function(){
     ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks. This definitely works, but I have to go with torazaburo's suggestion as passing in a controller does seem like a code smell. However, the question was 'how to observe a property within a controller' so this answer is technically the right one. And it's the correct answer too - it works.

Comment: Can you determine the item that is being added/removed for `observes('parentController.values.[]')` case.

Comment: not using this, but you can use `addArrayObserver` http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_addArrayObserver

Answer (score 22):

Passing an entire controller to a component is a massive code smell. It violates the basic principle of component encapsulation. If the "component" is so tightly coupled to the controller, then it's a view, from where you can access the controller by simply saying `this.controller`. Input to components should be strictly through parameters passed in when they are invoked. Output from components is through  `send`, which the controller can map to some behavior of its choosing in its view's template by saying `{{my-component action='eraseHardDisk'}}`.

You don't need to directly observe anything on the controller from within the component. If you call the component with `{{my-component param=someProperty}}`, then any change to the controller's `someProperty` will automatically be propagated to the `param` of the component. The component can then define some computed property on `param`, or observe it, or use it in its own template where it will be automatically kept up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of this code smell. I definitely did refactor my code to only pass in the required data as params and sent out output through the sendAction() function. You're right - the component should be independent; I read somewhere that the component knows of the controller but the controller knows not of the component and I misinterpreted it. Thank you; much appreciated.

Comment: The bindings don't work if Javascript based rendering is involved.