# How to determine item being added/removed to an observed array in ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

It explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26104867/3552579) how to observe items in an array with ember. My question is how can I determine the item being added/removed with this method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**addArrayObserver**](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_addArrayObserver) method to find items added/removed from an array.

The code will look something like this

```
that.get('content').addArrayObserver(this, {
  willChange: Ember.K,
  didChange: function(array, start, removeCount, addCount) {
    alert(array[start]);
  }
});
```

**[More information can be found here.](http://madhatted.com/2013/5/17/observing-enumerables-and-arrays-with-ember-js)**

**[Here is a link to a working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qaqine/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: why is it not possible to determine for `observes('items.[]')` method.

Comment: Basically observers just tell us that a value of property has changed. It doesn't give us information on what the change is. We use more specialized observers for that like addArrayObserver,addEnumberableObserver