# Assertion error Using {{controller}} removed in ember 2.0. How to pass/wrap controller object to component

Tags: ember.js

In ember 2.0, I am not able to wrap controller in my-component. it is showing compilation error.
Assertion Failed: Using `{{controller}}` or any path based on it  has been removed in Ember 2.0.

{{my-component ctrl=controller}}

How to achieve this ?. please guide me for alternative solution.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103711/can-an-ember-component-observe-a-controller-property/26105073#26105073.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use component actions which bubble to controller or passing controller properties in template declaration, if you need to access data from controller, instead of using `{{controller}}` directive.

Comment: I would like to call controller method transitionToRoute inside my nested component instead of bubbling action to controller. that's the reason for sending controller to component.

Comment: You should do it in controller and use action from component for that. This is how you do things in Ember.

Answer (score 0):

You just shouldn't do that. You should only pass in the properties that are relevant for the component instead of the whole controller.

For example if your component needs the properties `foo` and `bar` that are defined in the controller than you have to add them to your component call like `{{my-component componentAttribute=foo anotherAttribute=bar}}`. If you have to use the properties in some nested components you have to pass the properties in the most top level component and then pass it down to the component you want to make use of them.