# How to do the Synchronous call in the Ember js

Tags: ember.js

Here what i have done :
I have controller called "employee" and component "Department".

From controller i want to call the function of the component how can i it ?

controller: "Employee" ::

```
if (this.get("callMoveleft")) {
    this.set("callMoveleft", false);
    }    


else {
       this.set("callMoveleft", true);
      }
```

Component : "Department" ::

```
callMoveLeft: function () {
        console.log('Move left will be called');
    }.observes("callMoveleft"),
```

Department's function is not getting called. Please suggest me where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Doesnt really have much to do with being synchronous. Why dont you have the `callMoveLeft()` function on the controller? other than that here are some links that might help **1** - http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/getting-ember-components-to-respond-to-actions/ , **2** - http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call method of a component from a controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618604/how-to-call-method-of-a-component-from-a-controller)

Comment: @Craicerjack I want to call the function defined in the department component so after the callMoveLeft is called rather than displaying the console i will do function call from there. And that is also the reason that i have declare the function in the Component ! please tell me if i am doing any thing wrong as i am beginner in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a model that represents your component's state. This model will be available to the controller, so that it can call `.moveLeft()` on it.

The component should use this model's properties to display itself. Once the controller changes the model's state, the component will automatically update.

**UPD**

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wizepi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Can you elaborate ?? please give me some code ex. as i am new learner and slow learner or you can just add valuable comment in my code if i have done any thing wrong in this.

Comment: Is this still actual? I can provide an example.

Comment: Yes please it would be great for other who might visit the question.

Comment: I've added an extensive demo. Don't forget to upvote my answer. ;)