# Accessing component from controller

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way in EmberJS to access a component and it's methods from a controller? In pseudo code something like

```
this.getComponent('componentId').disable()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible and that is by design

> In Ember, views (Components are glorified views) know about their
>   controller, but controllers do NOT know about views. This is by design
>   (MVC) to keep things decoupled, and so you can have many views that
>   are being "powered" by a single controller, and the controller is none
>   the wiser. So when thinking about the relationship, changes can happen
>   to a controller and a view will react to those changes. So, just to
>   reiterate, you should never try to access a view/component from within
>   a controller

See this answer for more explanation and how to do it correctly [How to call method of a component from a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618604/how-to-call-method-of-a-component-from-a-controller)